# Out of the box Haskell plugin system

Tags: haskell

I've read about plugins in Haskell but I can't get a satisfactory way to my purposes (ideally to use in a production environment).

My plugin system goals are:

1. the production environment must to be out of the box (all precompiled).
2. to load plugins is enabled reset app/service but ideally it would load and update plugins on the fly.

One minimal example could be:

**The app/service ~ plugins interface**

```
module SharedTypes (PluginInterface (..)) where

data PluginInterface =
     PluginInterface { pluginName :: String
                     , runPlugin  :: Int -> Int }
```

**Some plugin list**

```
-- ~/plugins/plugin{Nth}.??   (with N=1..)
module Plugin{Nth}( getPlugin ) where

import SharedTypes

getPlugin :: PluginInterface
getPlugin = PluginInterface "{Nth}th plugin" $ \x -> {Nth} * x
```

**App/service**

```
...
loadPlugins :: FilePath -> IO [PluginInterface]
loadPlugins = undefined
...
```

I think using dynamic <s>compilation</s> link library (compiling each `Plugin{Nth}` as shared library) could works (as FFI) but

1. **How enumerate and load each shared library at runtime?** (get every `getPlugin` function point)
2. Exists some better way? (Eg. some *"magic"* process before run application/service)

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

## Full running example

Following the great @xnyhps answer, a full running example using `ghc 7.10`

**SharedTypes.hs**

```
module SharedTypes (
  PluginInterface (..)
) where

data PluginInterface =
     PluginInterface { pluginName :: String
                     , runPlugin  :: Int -> Int
                     }
```

**Plugin1.hs**

```
module Plugin1 (
  getPlugin
) where

import SharedTypes

getPlugin :: PluginInterface
getPlugin = PluginInterface "Plugin1" $ \x -> 1 * x
```

**Plugin2.hs**

```
module Plugin2 (
  getPlugin
) where

import SharedTypes

getPlugin :: PluginInterface
getPlugin = PluginInterface "Plugin2" $ \x -> 2 * x
```

**app.hs**

```
import SharedTypes
import System.Plugins.DynamicLoader
import System.Directory
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Applicative
import Data.List
import System.FilePath
import Control.Monad

loadPlugins :: FilePath -> IO [PluginInterface]
loadPlugins path = getDirectoryContents path >>= mapM loadPlugin . filter (".plugin" `isSuffixOf`)
  where loadPlugin file = do
          m <- loadModuleFromPath (combine path file)  -- absolute path
                                  (Just path)          -- base of qualified name (or you'll get not found)
          resolveFunctions
          getPlugin <- loadFunction m "getPlugin"
          return getPlugin

main = do

  -- and others used by plugins
  addDLL "/usr/lib/ghc-7.10.1/base_I5BErHzyOm07EBNpKBEeUv/libHSbase-4.8.0.0-I5BErHzyOm07EBNpKBEeUv-ghc7.10.1.so"
  loadModuleFromPath "/srv/despierto/home/josejuan/Projects/Solveet/PluginSystem/SharedTypes.o" Nothing

  plugins <- loadPlugins "/srv/despierto/home/josejuan/Projects/Solveet/PluginSystem/plugins"

  forM_ plugins $ \plugin -> do
    putStrLn $ "Plugin name: " ++ pluginName plugin
    putStrLn $ "     Run := " ++ show (runPlugin plugin 34)
```

**Compilation and execution**

```
[josejuan@centella PluginSystem]$ ghc --make -dynamic -fPIC -O3 Plugin1.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling SharedTypes      ( SharedTypes.hs, SharedTypes.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Plugin1          ( Plugin1.hs, Plugin1.o )
[josejuan@centella PluginSystem]$ ghc --make -dynamic -fPIC -O3 Plugin2.hs
[2 of 2] Compiling Plugin2          ( Plugin2.hs, Plugin2.o )
[josejuan@centella PluginSystem]$ mv Plugin1.o plugins/Plugin1.plugin
[josejuan@centella PluginSystem]$ mv Plugin2.o plugins/Plugin2.plugin
[josejuan@centella PluginSystem]$ ghc --make -dynamic -fPIC -O3 app.hs
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( app.hs, app.o )
Linking app ...
[josejuan@centella PluginSystem]$ ./app
Plugin name: Plugin1
     Run := 34
Plugin name: Plugin2
     Run := 68
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [the dynamic-loader package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dynamic-loader), which allows you to load extra object files or shared libraries into your process. (The version on Hackage doesn't work with 7.10, but the current [version on GitHub does](https://github.com/ggreif/dynamic-loader).)

With this, you could do:

```hs
import System.Plugins.DynamicLoader
import System.Directory

loadPlugins :: FilePath -> IO [PluginInterface]
loadPlugins path = do
    files <- getDirectoryContents path
    mapM (\plugin_path -> do
        m <- loadModuleFromPath (path ++ "/" ++ plugin_path) (Just path)
        resolveFunctions
        plugin <- loadFunction m "getPlugin"
        return plugin) files
```

However, you have to keep in mind that the entire process is **very unsafe**: if you change your `PluginInterface` data type and try to load a plugin compiled with the old version, your application will crash. You have to hope that the `getPlugin` function has type `PluginInterface`, there's no check for that. Lastly, if the plugin comes from an untrusted source, it could execute anything, even though the function you try to call should be pure in Haskel.

Comment: Thank you! I think is perfect! *"However"* yes of course, many additional things could be done to ensure compatibility (`getVersion`) and retrocompatibility (`getPlugin :: Maybe (a -> a)`, `getPluginV2 :: Maybe (a -> a -> a)`, and so on).