# Why is Dynamic Loader package unable to resolve functions?

Tags: haskell, ghc, dynamic-linking

I have been trying to use the [dynamic loader](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dynamic-loader) package which I found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681954/out-of-the-box-haskell-plugin-system). I am very new to Haskell so excuse me if I am making some incredibly rookie mistakes. My problem is that when I attempt to use the resolveFunctions function I get the following error:

```
DyanmicLoad-exe: /home/ubuntu/DynamicLoadTest/Plugin.o: unknown symbol `ghczmprim_GHCziCString_unpackCStringzh_closure'
DyanmicLoad-exe: user error (Unable to resolve functions!)
```

I would love it if someone could tell me possibly where I am going wrong here.

Here is my code (I am using the basic `stack new` structure):

**app/Main.hs**
Just the main function.

```
module Main where

import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = libMain
```

**src/Lib.hs**
The module is loaded in here.

```
module Lib
    ( libMain
    ) where
import System.Plugins.DynamicLoader
import System.Directory
import Interface
libMain :: IO ()
libMain = do currentDir <- System.Directory.getCurrentDirectory
             loadModuleFromPath (currentDir ++ "/Interface.o") Nothing
             putStrLn "Loaded Interface"
             loadedModule <- loadModuleFromPath (currentDir ++ "/Plugin.o") (Just currentDir)
             putStrLn "Loaded Plugin Module!"
             resolveFunctions
             putStrLn "Resolved Functions"
             plugin <- (loadFunction loadedModule "getPlugin") :: IO (JobInterface)
             putStrLn "Loaded Plugin"
             putStrLn (jobName plugin)
```

**src/Interface.hs**
This file is the "plugin interface"

```
module Interface (
   JobInterface (..)
) where

data JobInterface =
     JobInterface { jobName :: String
              , runJob :: Int -> Int
                  }
```

**src/Plugin.hs**
An example plugin. 
    module Plugin (
        getPlugin
    ) where

```
import Interface

getPlugin :: JobInterface
getPlugin = JobInterface "Hello" $ \x -> 1 * x
```

I am building with `stack build` followed by `stack ghc src/Plugin.hs src/Interface.hs`. I am running with `stack exec DyanmicLoad-exe`.

GHC version is 8.0.1

Full output:

```
$ stack exec DyanmicLoad-exe
Loaded Interface
Loaded Plugin Module!
DyanmicLoad-exe: /home/ubuntu/DynamicLoadTest/Plugin.o: unknown symbol `ghczmprim_GHCziCString_unpackCStringzh_closure'
DyanmicLoad-exe: user error (Unable to resolve functions!)
```

Edit 1:

Error with the -dynamic flag on build.

```
$ stack exec DyanmicLoad-exe
Loaded Interface
Loaded Plugin Module!
DyanmicLoad-exe: /home/ubuntu/DynamicLoadTest/Plugin.o: unhandled ELF relocation(RelA) type 42

DyanmicLoad-exe: user error (Unable to resolve functions!)
```

**Edit 2 .cabal file**

```
name:                DyanmicLoad
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            Initial project template from stack
description:         Please see README.md
homepage:            https://github.com/githubuser/DyanmicLoad#readme
license:             BSD3
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2017 Author name here
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  README.md
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
                      , Interface
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                      , dynamic-loader
                      , directory
  default-language:    Haskell2010

executable DyanmicLoad-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -dynamic -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , DyanmicLoad
  default-language:    Haskell2010

test-suite DyanmicLoad-test
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      test
  main-is:             Spec.hs
  build-depends:       base
                     , DyanmicLoad
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  default-language:    Haskell2010

source-repository head
  type:     git
  location: https://github.com/githubuser/DyanmicLoad
```

Comment: You say you're new to Haskell. Those libraries which implement dynamic code loading are advanced libraries for expert users. The vast majority of people never need them in their entire career. I think you're trying to run before you can walk. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: My overarching goal is to make a distributed MapReduce framework (university is fun). However this is, of course, a long way off. Right now my only goal is to load a plugin dynamically and call a function inside of it on some data. Honestly when I saw the package it seemed simple enough but I have now been staring at this for a very long time. Do you have any ideas as to why it is not working?

Comment: I think you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - that is to say, I don't think plugin-loader systems are likely to be a very effective way of achieving your goal of building a distributed MapReduce framework. What do you expect a hot code loader to be able to do for you (versus, say, a higher-order function)?

Comment: Distributing the user's map/reduce code to all the nodes in the cluster. The only other way would be recompilation on every node which seemed harder to me at first glance.

Comment: But you presumably don't want to allow the user to execute arbitrary Haskell code? That'd be potentially dangerous. Map-reduce is a relatively small problem, in the sense that you don't need all the power of a general-purpose programming language (Haskell) to write programs in a map-reduce style. I would consider designing a domain-specific language.

Comment: I was more trying to replicate something like Hadoop which takes in user compiled .jar. I am not worried about security so much because this is only a uni project that will be used by 2-3 people ever. The requirements require Haskell so that is what I am doing.

Comment: This is getting off-topic for SO, but have you looked at the [Cloud Haskell](http://haskell-distributed.github.io/) project?

Comment: I suspect it would help to build your program with `-dynamic` (not sure what the stacky way to say that is).

Comment: Cloud Haskell looks very interesting and relevant. Thanks for the link. I will try compiling with -dynamic when I get home.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have added the output when building with the -dynamic flag to the question. I don't know if this error takes me further away from or closer to my goals.

Comment: I've been trying this all morning with no luck. Similar error happens when using plugins package. Perhaps seek out alternative approaches. Even with distributing object files, you will still need programs on other side to run the distributed code and will therefore need a deploy those programs. Instead, as @Benjamin suggested, higher order function/domain specific language (DSL). Briefly, that means you will pass a value to distributed nodes which they will then know what to do with. This value can be complex, e.g. "DoX on Y then ReturnZ", this will be the DSL that you define. Good Luck.

Comment: You may be interested in [Cloud Haskell](http://haskell-distributed.github.io). I don't think your current approach will be be fruitful...